# How to change url to GET value with ajax send get requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to change url to `GET` value with ajax send get requests ?

i test my code , i will work good. But i want to change url to `GET` value too.
How can i do that ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function filters_fn()
    {
        $('#demoajax').hide();
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax
            (
                {
                    url: 'filter.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: $('#advance').serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data)
                        {
                            $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
                            $('#demoajax').show();
                            $('#demoajax').html(data);
                        }
                }
            );
        return false;
    }
</script>

    <form method="GET" id="advance" action="Javascript:void(0);">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check_box_all" name="check_box_all" value="All" onclick="filters_fn()">
        <span style=" color: #4d4d4d; ">
            All
        </span>
    </form> 
<div id="loading" style="display: none;">LOADING....</div>
<div id="demoajax"></div>
```

Comment: wat do you mean by "i want to change url to GET value too" ..?

Answer (score 0):

You can just direct the url to include GET values

```
url: 'filter.php?id=1&text=abc',
```

Then you can use php to get these by `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['abc'`

Answer (score 0):

The URL does not need at have the ? as you would have in a GET query string because the way ajax works it doesn't send it along in the browser as you would through a link it sends the data to a php or other file then from there you return a value through an echo or print command. Ajax then gets that data back in its done function as you use the data without having to reload the browser page.

Comment: can i send url browser with ajax ?

Comment: ajax is used when you don't want the page to redirect or refresh so it runs the script usually php and gets a return value back. normally you would put a event.preventDefault(); in your function to prevent the form from submitting if you don't then the form will submit and not get the result back from the ajax call. Actually just noticed the return false that will do the same thing and not submit the form.

Comment: If you want the URL in the browser for your user to bookmark then you will need to have the form actually submit and not use ajax. ajax is meant to do it behind the scenes without the need to send it via browser.